# Monotone function is Borel

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Equipping $\mathbb{R}$ with the Borel sigma-algebra $B(\mathbb{R})$, let f be a monotone function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Consider I as an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\alpha < \beta \in f^{−1}(I)$ then $[\alpha, \beta] \subset f^{−1}(I)$.

Using this fact how to deduce that f is Borel?

Comment: Intervals generate your sigma algebra, thus you only need to verify that $f^{-1}(I)$ is Borelian.

Comment: Also convex parts of $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace
 I didn't understand what you mean, could you please explain more? thanks in advance

Comment: In summary you should show that $f^{-1}(I)$ is an interval